# Asp.net Core 6.0 InvalidOperationException: Cannot create a DbSet for 'IdentityUser' because this type is not included in the model for the context

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

i have developed a web app in which i want to use Microsoft Identity (with individual users) and Postgresql as a db.
In this webapp i store ef core dbcontext in a separate project / layer and i set up the Program.cs startup in this manner (i have omitted the other rows):

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    
// getting connection string from Postgresql db
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("NINIVE_DB");

//add dbcontext of the referenced project        
builder.Services.AddDbContext<NiniveContext>(options =>
        options.UseNpgsql(connectionString));
        
//set the Postgresql db as a source of the identity users   
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<NiniveContext>();
```

But when i try to use the login page i get the error that i've specified in the object of this post.
I check the class DbContext e i find all the tables that are requested for the Identity.
Here is the first part of the DbContext class:

```
public partial class NiniveContext : DbContext
{
    public NiniveContext()
    {
    }

    public NiniveContext(DbContextOptions<NiniveContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<AspNetRole> AspNetRoles { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<AspNetRoleClaim> AspNetRoleClaims { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUser> AspNetUsers { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserClaim> AspNetUserClaims { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserLogin> AspNetUserLogins { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserToken> AspNetUserTokens { get; set; }
```

I've see tons of articles but never is useful for me!
Any idea about this?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does the Database already exist or are you trying to create it through the Code-First approach?

Comment: Also, the most obvious thing to check for is whether the DbSet class `AspNetUser` is inheriting from `IdentityUser` properly

Comment: Introduce `public virtual DbSet<IdentityUser> IdentityUsers { get; set; }` in your `DbConext` or register entity in `OnModelCreating` - `modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>();`

Comment: @Tiramonium the database exist and i have done a workaround to obtain the dbcontext as i use Postgresql

Comment: @Tiramonium probably is the second ,i see that the class AspNetUser have to be derive from that, but how i can do that?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv i introduce that but i get a error

Comment: Hi, if you use the Identity, your NiniveContext should inherits from `IdentityDbContext` instead of `DbContext`. By default the IdentityUser is a table with GUID id, do you change the type. Did you use the default table in Identity or custom the table?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the Identity Framework classes or use them as they are. `AspNetUser` in your example would be one such overriding class of the included `IdentityUser` class in Identity Framework. You don't need to override all of them, mind you. Depending on your authorization setup, you can choose between Role Claims (Permissions) authorization based only, User Claims (Permissions) authorization based only or a combination of both

In case you plan on using Annotations on them of any kind, be them for database modelling, model validation or any other kind, you may want to override the included classes, like so:

```
public class AspNetRole :      IdentityRole<(primary key type)> { }
public class AspNetRoleClaim : IdentityRoleClaim<(primary key type)> { }
public class AspNetUser :      IdentityUser<(primary key type)> { }
public class AspNetUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<(primary key type)> { }
public class AspNetUserLogin:  IdentityUserLogin<(primary key type)> { }
public class AspNetUserToken : IdentityUserToken<(primary key type)> { }
public class AspNetUserRole :  IdentityUserRole<(primary key type)> { }
```

You should also create a different context class for Identity configuration since it implements `IdentityDbContext` rather than `DbContext` from Entity Framework. This class can take a couple of different method signatures, depending on which included classes you implemented or not, according to your authorization setup

This doesn't necessarily mean the data needs to be in separate databases, however, they just need different Context classes. They could be placed on a same database but under different schemas, for example. This is an example with all the derived classes from above implementing both Role and User Claims:

```
public class NiniveIdentityContext :
    IdentityDbContext<AspNetUser, AspNetRole, Guid,
    AspNetUserClaim, AspNetUserRole, AspNetUserLogin,
    AspNetRoleClaim, AspNetUserToken> { }
```

Then your application context class would implement `DbContext` for your application data:

```
public class NiniveContext : DbContext { }
```

Then when setting up the application, you'd use them like so:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// getting connection string from PostgreSQL DB
var connectionString = builder.Configuration
    .GetConnectionString("NINIVE_DB");

// getting connection string from PostgreSQL DB for Identity connection
var connectionIdentityString = builder.Configuration
    .GetConnectionString("NINIVE_IDENTITY_DB");

// add DbContext of the referenced project
builder.Services
    .AddDbContext<NiniveContext>(options => options.UseNpgSql(connectionString));

// add IdentityDbContext of the current project
builder.Services
    .AddDbContext<NiniveIdentityContext>(options => options.UseNpgSql(connectionIdentityString));

// set the PostgreSQL DB as a source of the Identity users   
builder.Services
    .AddDefaultIdentity<AspNetUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<NiniveIdentityContext>();
```